# For which permutations groups $G$ do we have $G.v = Sn.v$ for all $v$?

Tags: permutations, representation-theory, polytopes

My question is related to this topic : [Permutation of coordinates: how many linearly independent vectors will this generate?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3394373/permutation-of-coordinates-how-many-linearly-independent-vectors-will-this-gene?newreg=2a1ca82f2eca4bf69093909c18912fd1)

I noticed that for $n \ge 3$, we have $A_nv = S_nv$ for all vectors $v$.

My question is : what are precisely the permutations groups $G$ for which $Gv = S_nv$ for all $v$ ?

We can show that *transitivity* is a necessary condition for such a group and, stronger, being *primitive* (see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_permutation_group) is a necessary condition too.

By this work : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/222651063_Permutation_polytopes_and_indecomposable_elements_in_permutation_groups, it appears $2$-*transitivity* is a sufficient condition.

But do you see a necessary and sufficient condition ?

Thank you for your help ! :-)

Comment: Not everyone here is in your time zone.