# Average number of the maximum amount of fixed points of permutation in a partition of $S_n$

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

> Consider the symmetric group $S_n$ and, for each $\sigma \in S_n$, let
> $f(\sigma)$ be the number of fixed points of $\sigma$. Now let $g$ be
> the permutation such that $g(i)=i+1$ for $i=1,...,n-1$ and $g(n)=1$. We can partition $S_n$ in
> $(n-1)!$ sets of the form $$\sigma _g = \{\sigma, \sigma \circ g ,
>  \sigma \circ g ^2 ,..., \sigma \circ g ^{n-1}\}$$ for all $\sigma \in
>  S_n$ such that $\sigma(1)=1$. Let $$h(\sigma _g) = \max \{f(\pi) \mid \pi
>  \in  \sigma _g\}. $$ Show that the average of $h(\sigma _g)$ for all
> $\sigma \in S_n$ such that $\sigma(1)=1$ is $3$ if $n\rightarrow
>  \infty$.

The only thing I can do is show that the average of $f(\sigma)$ is $1$ if $n\rightarrow
 \infty$ using the formulas in [1]. I also tried to adapt the approaches in [2], but with no success. At last, I attempted to rewrite the problem in terms of permutation matrices, where $f$ is the trace of the matrix and apply some properties, also without success.

EDIT: so, from Carl Schildkraut's comment and also [3], it seems that this value explodes (although very slowly) as $n\rightarrow \infty$, as it's most likely $$\left( \frac{\log(n)}{\log(\log(n))} \right)$$ asymptotically, because, in each set $\sigma_g$, the distribution of the number of fixed points likely is $n$ Poisson distributions, so the expected maximum, according to [3], should be like that.
So this question is most likely wrong and this limit may well be unbounded.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers

[2] [Fixed points of permutation groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4240957/fixed-points-of-permutation-groups)

[3] https://arxiv.org/pdf/0903.4373.pdf

Comment: But then $g(n-1)=0\notin\{1,\dots,n\}$, isn't it?

Comment: @fitzcarraldo, we apply $g$ to a set and its value must be at least 1, because this set always has a permutation that fixes at least the number 1. It's impossible for this set to contain only permutations that have no fixed point.

Comment: @fitzcarraldo I think $g$ is supposed to be the permutation mapping $i$ to the number in $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ equivalent to $i+1$ modulo $n$, not the number in $\{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}$. So $g(n-1)=n$, and $g(n)=1$.

Comment: Oh, now I see that I used the same letter $g$ in two ways. Edited. Sorry for that.

Comment: Are you sure of this result? I have a (rather poor) heuristic that suggests this average should grow like $\Theta(\frac{\log n}{\log\log n})$, and numerical experiments give that this average should increase in $n$ and is larger than $3$ for large-ish $n$.